# is there a way to get a list of all components in an angular+angularjs project?

Tags: angular, angularjs, intellij-idea

Is there a way to get a list of all ui components in an angular+angularjs project?
I am wondering if maybe there's an IntelliJ plugin or a known script or something that could extract that list (of components and where it is being used, maybe like a tree).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be a documentation generator such as [Compodoc](https://compodoc.app/). This will give you a list of components, a DOM node map, and allow you to drill down into each component and see its properties and methods.